# CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.ApplyLogOnInfo Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

what is wrong with this code:

```
ReportDocument cryrpt = new ReportDocument();
            TableLogOnInfos crtablelogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtablelogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo crconnectioninfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables CrTables;

            cryrpt.Load("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\minfatora11-7--\\minfatora\\minfatora\\Treasury_account_out_come.rpt");

            crconnectioninfo.ServerName = "localhost";
            crconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = "MNFATOR";
            crconnectioninfo.UserID = "ICMADMIN";
            crconnectioninfo.Password = "ICMADMIN";

            CrTables = cryrpt.Database.Tables;

            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }





            cryrpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "select * from tblxxx where xxx=2";
            cryrpt.Refresh();
            allReportViewer.ReportSource = cryrpt;
```

i get error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
on the line:

```
CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `CrTables` is `null`, when you get your table in this line

```
CrTables = cryrpt.Database.Tables;
```

1. You can verify the path of load
2. Or check syntax of your file Treasury_account_out_come.rpt

Answer (score -1):

```
cryrpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{tblxxx.xxx}=2";
```

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation as to why the original code was incorrect and how your code corrects that?

Comment: To be sure add a 'formula field' to your Crystal Report file and note field name in it
{tblxxx.fieldxxx} is the correct format for field name. Regards